Is the Dungeon of the Unknown based on player characters?
We are playing through the Dungeon of the Unknown that goes by the weird name "Quasqueton" from the original D&D Basic Set introductory adventure In Search of the Unknown (updated and converted to 5e).
What I find quite peculiar on reading the adventure is that the dungeon effectively is the home base that some adventurers built for themselves.

The deeds and adventures of these two characters were never well known, since they both kept their distance from civilization. Some say, and perhaps rightly so, that their motives were based on greed and some kind of vague (or chaotic) evil.

The adventure also provides some detail on the adventures of those two, for example how they beat back a barbarian invasion.

Rogahn and Zelligar capped their reputation of power when they joined forces to
stop a barbarian invasion threatening the great valley below. In a crucial battle at a narrow pass in the hills, the two combined powerful forces and decisively turned back the invasion. Rogahn slew a horde of barbarians single-handedly and Zelligar's powerful magic put their army to flight.

And pictures in Roghan's bedroom show him in various exploits, too, like slaying a dragon, or the story above, beating back the invasion on a mountain pass. The trophy room has the fitting dragon paws on exhibit, next to a stuffed cockatrice, and barbarian flags. This is all not that different from how our other party's home-base looks like. We also splurge on nice furniture and hoist trophies of defeated monsters to the walls.
These two are described as allegedly greedy and evil, yet the same might have applied to of many player parties of the era, who engaged in murder hobo activities. There is a reason Gygax statted all the shops and guards in the Keep on the Borderlands and the Village of Hommlet, as you never could know what the PCs would try to plunder next in their quest for power and riches.
All of which makes me wonder: did the author, Mike Carr, sneak names, PCs and stories from his home campaign into the module? After all, it is a somewhat unusual setting, compared to dungeons of evil priests, slavers, giants and demi-liches.

"The trophy room has the fitting dragon paws on exhibit" . . . is some word in there missing or wrong?  Also, fwiw, Quasqueton is a town in Iowa in the US.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasqueton,_Iowa).

There are four dragon paws in the trophy room, matching that he slew a dragon. Interesting about Quasqueton. Carr is from Minnesota according to his Wikipedia page, but maybe he lived in Ohio for some time?

Mike Carr is still alive. You could try to reach out to him.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Okay, makes sense.

"Before creating [the module], Carr, now 72 and living north of Milwaukee, lived in Cedar Rapids from 1974 to 1975, working at the Ground Round restaurant on First Avenue East. That’s when he first heard the name Quasqueton that he would incorporate in his fictional setting when he was in his 20s."  https://www.thegazette.com/news/why-quasqueton-shows-up-in-dungeon-dragons/

@KorvinStarmast Your comment triggered me to do some sleuthing, and it turns out, Mike Carr went on the record on this in an audio interview.

It isn't, except for the name
The characters of Rogahn and Zelligar were not from his home game. While Carr was an early player in the Blackmoor campaign, and played the first cleric in the history of RPGs, named Bishop Carr, he stated that

my primary interest was in historical games rather than fantasy games (which is still the case), I didn't play too often and didn't make any progress with that character. It's ironic that I knew both Dave Arneson and Gary Gygax fairly well and enjoyed their company from time to time, but never played much D&D with either of them.

Instead, he had volunteered to write the adventure to help beginning players to learn the ropes of D&D, leveraging the guidance on adventure design from the The Underworld & Wilderness Adventures booklet of OD&D.
This was confirmed in an interview on the Save or Die Podcast (December 4, 2010, about 32:18 minutes in), where he stated that the background wasn't based on any pre-existing adventures:

Was the background of the module from maybe, you know, was that based on something you had already gamed, or was it just kinda, made up whole cloth, specifically, for the module? It was made up. It was made up whole cloth. The point that I made in there was, you can take this, now, once you become a Dungeon Master, and you are creating your own situation. You can use this, if you like, as part of your world, and it can be off in one corner or whatever, as a reference point. No, it was created specifically for that module, and, out of whole cloth, as you say.

The name of Quasqueton however is taken from a real world town in Iowa. As recounted by Fred Love, a Quasqueton native, who reached out to Carr via his publisher:

As it happens, the dungeon likely would have received a different name were it not for the Ground Round restaurant chain. Carr worked for the Ground Round in Roseville, Minnesota, during college. His job prospects upon graduation looked bleak, so he entered Ground Round's management training program, which sent him to the restaurant chain's Cedar Rapids, Iowa, location from 1974 to 1975. Carr first encountered the name Quasqueton during that fateful time in Cedar Rapids, which is located in an adjacent county from my hometown. The name stuck with him when he started work for TSR in March 1976.
"In developing the backstory and setting [for B1], I wanted to give this mythical place a distinctive and extraordinary name," Carr said. "During my two years of living in Cedar Rapids, I became aware of the town called Quasqueton and that place name qualified perfectly, so that's the name I chose."

The story is also corroborated in this piece by The Gazette.

Well done on the deep dive!
